# toplevel constant ApplicationController referenced by Children::ApplicationController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, applicationcontroller

I am merging two applications school and children. Each working fine With children application nested in school application. Each of them have its own Database.
Here is part of the tree for school  app:

> app/controllers/application_controller.rb
>   
> app/controllers/user.rb
>   
>  ....
>   app/controllers/children/application_controller.rb
>   
> app/controllers/children/user.rb
>   ....

and had these warning:

> toplevel constant ApplicationController referenced by Children::ApplicationController
>   
> toplevel constant User referenced by Children::User

in app/controllers/children/application_controller.rb i have 

class Children::ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

in app/controllers/application_controller.rb i have 

class class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

the  nested ApplicationController is not loaded.the namespace is not working?

Answer (score 0):

1-
    `toplevel constant ApplicationController referenced by Children::ApplicationController`

I end up consolidating both applicationController in ONE applicationController ie adding content of the nested applicatioController (Children) in school applicationController to have just one applicationController.

2-
    `toplevel constant User referenced by Children::User`

I **renamed** the users_controller.rb to children_users_controller.rb. And you have this first line in the controller
      `class Children::ChildrenUsersController < Children::ApplicationController`

It was a name conflict even though they were from two different namespace! find some tips from [here](https://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-core/browse_thread/thread/bab5e87ee10d2ecb?pli=1)
hope it helps